# How should i add RAW IP packet to NDIS type Mobile broadband for support?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, ndis

I'm trying to add support for Windows 7 Mobile Broadband Adapters to a  LWF driver .

So now I need to connect with USB dongle . I have a 
dongle with support RAS modem and NDIS . My application can connect with RAS 
modem on dongle . I have a interface list which shows the list of active 
adapters . But when I set NDIS on dongle , I can't see that adapter (3g network 
card ) on that list . After setting ( ip automatically ,DHCP automatically from 
adapter properties ) I can see that adapter is active . But I can't connect via 
NDIS . But I can Connect RAS modem with dongle .

My application has 2 INF files . In Mux ,I have one INF 
file and also in virtual adapter another INF file . So I am confused that which one I should modify ?

I got good documentation from Microsoft regarding INF file changes for mobile broadband .

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557185(v=vs.85).aspx

so in MUX INF files has :

```
[INSTALL.NDI]

HKR, Ndi, FilterClass, , custom
HKR, Ndi, FilterType, 0x00010001, 0x00000002
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, UpperRange, , "noupper"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, LowerRange, , "nolower"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes, , "nolower, ethernet, wan"
HKR, Ndi, FilterRunType, 0x00010001, 1
```

and i chnaged to

```
[INSTALL.NDI]

HKR, Ndi, FilterClass, , custom
HKR, Ndi, FilterType, 0x00010001, 0x00000002
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, UpperRange, , "noupper"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, LowerRange, , "nolower"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, FilterMediaTypes, , "nolower, ethernet, wan, ppip"
HKR, Ndi, FilterRunType, 0x00010001, 1
```

`ppip` is added here ..

in Virtual adpter INF file

```
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, UpperRange, , "ndis5"
HKR, Ndi\Interfaces, LowerRange, , "ethernet"
```

and I got another information about packet (buffer list )

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559110(v=vs.85).aspx

but my problem is where should I put this code ? before send or receive function ?

In `filter.cpp` file , I added `NdisMediumWirelessWan` to the function

```
NDIS_STATUS CFilter::Attach(
    IN NDIS_HANDLE NdisFilterHandle,
    IN PNDIS_FILTER_ATTACH_PARAMETERS AttachParameters
) {

    NDIS_STATUS status = NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    if (
        (AttachParameters->MiniportMediaType != NdisMedium802_3)
        && (AttachParameters->MiniportMediaType != NdisMediumWan)
        && (AttachParameters->MiniportMediaType != NdisMediumNative802_11)
        && (AttachParameters->MiniportMediaType != NdisMediumWirelessWan)

    ) {
        status = NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
        goto myExit;
    }
```

I have `sendbufferlist` function :

```
VOID CFilter::SendNetBufferLists(
    IN PNET_BUFFER_LIST NetBufferLists,
    IN NDIS_PORT_NUMBER PortNumber,
    IN ULONG SendFlags
) {

    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pSendNetBufferList = NULL;
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pSendNetBufferListComplete = NULL;

    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pNetBufferList = NetBufferLists;
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pNextNetBufferList = NULL;

     ***  i am doing RAW IP packet here ***

    NdisSetNblFlag(pNetBufferList, NDIS_NBL_FLAGS_IS_IPV4);
    NET_BUFFER_LIST_INFO(pNetBufferList, NetBufferListFrameType) = 0x0008; 

    *** END my IP raw Packet code ****

    while (pNetBufferList) {
        pNextNetBufferList = NET_BUFFER_LIST_NEXT_NBL(pNetBufferList);
        NET_BUFFER_LIST_NEXT_NBL(pNetBufferList) = NULL;

        if (pNetBufferList->ChildRefCount != 0) {
            DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVNETWORK_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "!!! [%p] 
CFilter::SendNetBufferLists(): pNetBufferList->ChildRefCount != 0\n", this);
        }

        PNET_BUFFER pNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(pNetBufferList);
        PNET_BUFFER pNextNetBuffer = NULL;
        while (pNetBuffer) {
            pNextNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_NEXT_NB(pNetBuffer);
```

is this correct way to connect NDIS type mobile broadband ? or How should I modify this code to get support for NDIS type Mobile broadband . because I can connect RAS type on USB dongle .

please help me .

Thanks & regards

Comment: I'm confused - you say LWF, but then you describe the INFs of a MUX.   Which is it?  For what it's worth, I've never heard of anybody getting a MUX to work over a mobile broadband adapter.  But LWFs work just fine; the OS even includes several that have MBB support.

Comment: @JeffreyTippet    I have a Filter driver . That's a MUX Filter and a Virtual miniport . So my application contain both MUX Filter INF and virtual miniport INF file . How can i support to mobile broadband ? Only change to miniport INF file ?

Comment: @JeffreyTippet can i use NDIS MUX Intermediate Driver to get support for Mobile broadband support ?

Comment: After searching i got information like  => NDIS 5 Intermediate (IM) Filter Drivers (Windows XP) and 
=> NDIS 6 Lightweight Filter (LWF) Drivers (Windows Vista and higher)  .... Can i get mobile broadband support on IM filter Filter ?